Oracle database connection through VBA
I'm not able to connect to Oracle database through VBA code.
My connection string code is as follows
strcon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & dbHost_Name & ")(PORT=" & dbPort & "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & dbService_Name "))); uid=" & dbUserName & "; pwd=" & dbPassword & ";"
And the error is as below:
Error no 3704
Description: Operation is not allowed when object is closed.
Can anyone please guide me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Are you saying that you get the error message at the line you posted? That cannot be the case.  By the way, the line you posted is syntactically incorrect resp. has a minor formatting issue. I am afraid you have to post a bit more of the relevant code.

Connection String Formatting: Your connection string has a minor formatting issue. Specifically, you are missing an ampersand (&) for concatenation before dbService_Name. Also, make sure all variables (dbHost_Name, dbPort, dbService_Name, dbUserName, dbPassword) are correctly defined and contain valid values.
Let's assume for this post that your connection string is valid
   strcon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & _
    dbHost_Name & ")(PORT=" & _
    dbPort & "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & _
    dbService_Name & "))); uid=" & _
    dbUserName & "; pwd=" & dbPassword & ";"

Opening the Connection: Here is a step-by-step example of how to properly open the connection and execute a query:
Dim conn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strcon As String
Dim dbHost_Name As String
Dim dbPort As String
Dim dbService_Name As String
Dim dbUserName As String
Dim dbPassword As String

' Initialize the database connection parameters
dbHost_Name = "your_host_name"
dbPort = "your_port"
dbService_Name = "your_service_name"
dbUserName = "your_username"
dbPassword = "your_password"

' Corrected connection string
strcon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & _
    dbHost_Name & ")(PORT=" & _
    dbPort & "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & _
    dbService_Name & "))); uid=" & _
    dbUserName & "; pwd=" & dbPassword & ";"

' Create the ADODB connection object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Open the connection  <= You will get an error here in case the connection string is wrong
conn.Open strcon

' Check if the connection is open 
If conn.State = 1 Then
    ' Execute a sample query
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM your_table", conn

    ' Check if the recordset is open
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Process your data here
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
    End If

    ' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Connection failed."
End If

' Close the connection
conn.Close


Hi, thanks for quick response. Yes, as you said the error is at the connection open code. I have made the above changes which you suggested but the error is same. Upon my search I found it may be due to some driver issue. Could you please suggest me regarding the drivers required to run this code. I'm using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.20.0.0
Thank you!!

I am afraid I am not of any help here in suggesting a driver. Maybe you check on the connection string: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ and make sure you've got the right values for dbHost_Name, dbPort, dbService_Name, dbUserName, dbPassword.
